# Open XML Table Generation Using Generic List

Tags: c#, openxml

I have written a method to insert a table in a word document using Open XML.  The method accepts a generic list and a few parameters to control number of columns, column headings etc.

That all works fine.

However when populating the cells in the table I want to pull out the values for each row and place them in their corresponding columns.  Given the names of the properties are going to change depending on the contents of the generic list, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Anyone that can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
void InsertTable<T>(List<T> tableData, int[] tableHeadingCount, string[] columnHeadings, string locationInDocument)
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_newDocument, true))
                {
                    var docPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                    var doc = docPart.Document;

                    var table = new Table();
                    var tableBorderTop = new TopBorder();
                    var tableBorderBottom = new BottomBorder();
                    var tableBorderLeft = new LeftBorder();
                    var tableBorderRight = new RightBorder();
                    var tableBorderHorizontal = new InsideHorizontalBorder();
                    var tableBorderVertical = new InsideVerticalBorder();
                    var tableProperties = new TableProperties();
                    var borders = new TableBorders();


                    // Set Border Styles for Table
                    tableBorderTop.Val = BorderValues.Single;
                    tableBorderTop.Size = 6;
                    tableBorderBottom.Val = BorderValues.Single;
                    tableBorderBottom.Size = 6;
                    tableBorderLeft.Val = BorderValues.Single;
                    tableBorderLeft.Size = 6;
                    tableBorderRight.Val = BorderValues.Single;
                    tableBorderRight.Size = 6;
                    tableBorderHorizontal.Val = BorderValues.Single;
                    tableBorderHorizontal.Size = 6;
                    tableBorderVertical.Val = BorderValues.Single;
                    tableBorderVertical.Size = 6;

                    // Assign Border Styles to Table Borders
                    borders.TopBorder = tableBorderTop;
                    borders.BottomBorder = tableBorderBottom;
                    borders.LeftBorder = tableBorderLeft;
                    borders.RightBorder = tableBorderRight;
                    borders.InsideHorizontalBorder = tableBorderHorizontal;
                    borders.InsideVerticalBorder = tableBorderVertical;


                    // Append Border Styles to Table Properties
                    tableProperties.Append(borders);

                    // Assign Table Properties to Table
                    table.Append(tableProperties);

                    var tableRowHeader = new TableRow();
                    tableRowHeader.Append(new TableRowHeight() { Val = 2000 });

                    for (int i = 0; i < tableHeadingCount.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var tableCellHeader = new TableCell();

                        //Assign Font Properties to Run
                        var runPropHeader = new RunProperties();
                        runPropHeader.Append(new Bold());
                        runPropHeader.Append(new Color() { Val = "000000" });

                        //Create New Run
                        var runHeader = new Run();
                        //Assign Font Properties to Run
                        runHeader.Append(runPropHeader);

                        var columnHeader = new Text();
                        //Assign the Pay Rule Name to the Run
                        columnHeader = new Text(columnHeadings[i]);

                        runHeader.Append(columnHeader);

                        //Create Properties for Paragraph
                        var justificationHeader = new Justification();
                        justificationHeader.Val = JustificationValues.Left;

                        var paraPropsHeader = new ParagraphProperties(justificationHeader);
                        SpacingBetweenLines spacing = new SpacingBetweenLines() { Line = "240", LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto, Before = "0", After = "0" };
                        paraPropsHeader.Append(spacing);

                        var paragraphHeader = new Paragraph();

                        paragraphHeader.Append(paraPropsHeader);
                        paragraphHeader.Append(runHeader);
                        tableCellHeader.Append(paragraphHeader);

                        var tableCellPropertiesHeader = new TableCellProperties();
                        var tableCellWidthHeader = new TableCellWidth();

                        tableCellPropertiesHeader.Append(new Shading() { Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear, Color = "auto", Fill = "#C0C0C0" });

                        var textDirectionHeader = new TextDirection();
                        textDirectionHeader.Val = TextDirectionValues.BottomToTopLeftToRight;
                        tableCellPropertiesHeader.Append(textDirectionHeader);

                        tableCellWidthHeader.Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa;
                        tableCellWidthHeader.Width = "2000";

                        tableCellPropertiesHeader.Append(tableCellWidthHeader);

                        tableCellHeader.Append(tableCellPropertiesHeader);
                        tableRowHeader.Append(tableCellHeader);

                    }

                    tableRowHeader.AppendChild(new TableHeader());

                    table.Append(tableRowHeader);

                    //Create New Row in Table for Each Record

                    foreach (var record in tableData)
                    {
                        var tableRow = new TableRow();
                        for (int i = 0; i < tableHeadingCount.Length; i++)
                        {

                            //**** This is where I dynamically want to iterate through selected properties and output the value ****

                            var propertyText = "Test";  

                            var tableCell = new TableCell();

                            //Assign Font Properties to Run
                            var runProp = new RunProperties();
                            runProp.Append(new Bold());
                            runProp.Append(new Color() { Val = "000000" });


                            //Create New Run
                            var run = new Run();
                            //Assign Font Properties to Run
                            run.Append(runProp);

                            //Assign the text to the Run
                            var text = new Text(propertyText);
                            run.Append(text);

                            //Create Properties for Paragraph
                            var justification = new Justification();
                            justification.Val = JustificationValues.Left;
                            var paraProps = new ParagraphProperties(justification);

                            var paragraph = new Paragraph();

                            paragraph.Append(paraProps);
                            paragraph.Append(run);
                            tableCell.Append(paragraph);

                            var tableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties();
                            var tableCellWidth = new TableCellWidth();
                            tableCellWidth.Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa;
                            tableCellWidth.Width = "2000";
                            tableCellProperties.Append(tableCellWidth);
                            tableCell.Append(tableCellProperties);
                            tableRow.Append(tableCell);
                        }

                        table.Append(tableRow);
                    }

                    var res = from bm in docPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                              where bm.Name == locationInDocument
                              select bm;
                    var bookmark = res.SingleOrDefault();
                    var parent = bookmark.Parent; // bookmark's parent element
                    Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph();
                    parent.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraph);
                    if (bookmark != null)
                    {
                        newParagraph.InsertBeforeSelf(table);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by tackling the problem another way.  Essentially rather than passing a List to the Insert Table Method.  I decided to Pass a Multi-Dimensional Array with all the data need for the table including the table headings.  This essentially meant that the Insert Table method would be more generic and any customization i.e. Generating Data, Specifying Column Headings etc would be done in the Method calling Insert Table.